# Redirect old url to new url with .htaccess redirection

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect all of the following type of links:

**LINKS TO BE REDIRECTED:**

- https://www.canvas-events.co.uk/venues/landmark-buildings

**REDIRECT TO THIS LINK DYNAMICALLY:**

- https://www.canvas-events.co.uk/hire/venues/landmark-buildings

**NOTE:** I want to redirect all url's which contains alphabets naming instead of integers because we have an another route which has the same route structure too, i.e. `venues/293` & `/venues/landmark-buildings` the only difference is the use of alphabet based delimiter instead of integer one. I need to redirect the link with alpahbets delimiter not the integer one.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/venues/([A-Za-z/-_]+)/?$ https://www.canvas-events.co.uk/hire/venues/$1
```

The pattern above only accepts characters ranging from `A-Z a-z` and some URL characters `/ -_` .

Comment: Thanks for the answer but due to the character `/` in the regex expression all of the integer URL's were matching as well which I removed and now only alphabets,hyphens and underscore based url's are matching. The modified expression is `RedirectMatch 301 ^/venues/([A-Za-z-_]+)/?$ /hire/venues/$1`

Comment: Is there anyway I can make sure to redirect `http://example.com/app_dev.php/venues/landmark-buildings` based url's to `http://example.com/app_dev.php/hire/venues/landmark-buildings` as well? To pass url's to dev environment based controller as well?